# error in implementationg enum in c++ inside class

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a class representing a card. but i faced this error while compiling.

> error: expected `;' before "suit".

Can anyone help what is problem with this code?

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Card {

private:
       Card::Suit suit;
       Card::CardName cardName;
public:
    enum Suit {Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, UNKNOWN_SUIT};
    enum  CardName {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, UNKNOWN_CARDNAME};
    class NotInitalised : public exception{};
    Card ();
    Card (int card);
    Card (Card::Suit s, Card::CardName n);
    void setCard(Card::Suit, Card::CardName);
    Card::Suit getSuit();
    Card::CardName getCardName();
    Card::CardName getCardName(int);
    int getCardValue();
    string toString();
};
```

Comment: You're inside the same scope where the enums were declared. Therefore, the types don't need scope resolution.

Comment: By the way, it works when you move the enums to the top of the class: http://liveworkspace.org/code/67cd31d07367763b0e2d5c4de5ae09cd

Comment: Unrelated: break yourself of that `using namespace std;` in a header file right now. the potential side effects are not worth the convenience (and there is *no* convenience). Use namespace-qualified ids/types in your headers. (ex. `std::string`)

Answer (score 2):

As always in C++ you need to declare something before you use it. You must therefore move the definition of enum Suit before the declaration of the suit member.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the enum definitions before the point you use them. For instance something like:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Card {

public: 
    enum Suit {Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, UNKNOWN_SUIT};
    enum  CardName {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, UNKNOWN_CARDNAME};
private:
       Card::Suit suit;
       Card::CardName cardName;
public:
    class NotInitalised : public exception{};
    Card ();
    Card (int card);
    Card (Card::Suit s, Card::CardName n);
    void setCard(Card::Suit, Card::CardName);
    Card::Suit getSuit();
    Card::CardName getCardName();
    Card::CardName getCardName(int);
    int getCardValue();
    string toString();
};
```

should work.

Also you don't need to qualify the uses of the enums inside your class definition, i.e. instead of

```
Card::Suit suit;
```

you can use

```
Suit suit;
```

I usually declare all the public elements of a class before the private ones, since I want to have the public interface of the class when I look at it, but this is just a style preference that others may not agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Remove scope resolution operator and move type declaration before use of that type

You class will look like as follows:

```
using namespace std;
class Card {

private:
    enum Suit {Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, UNKNOWN_SUIT};
    enum  CardName {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, UNKNOWN_CARDNAME};

     Suit suit;
     CardName cardName;
public:
    class NotInitalised : public exception{};
    Card ();
    Card (int card);
    Card (Suit s, CardName n);
    void setCard(Suit, CardName);
    Suit getSuit();
    CardName getCardName();
    CardName getCardName(int);
    int getCardValue();
    string toString();
};
```